# Farm of Jenkins - multiple Jenkins Masters

Tags: jenkins

I have a few instances of Jenkins. Each Jenkins has its own configuration, nodes etc.
There are also proper aliases for them:

- jenkins.domain.tld - "main" Jenkins
- name1.jenkins.domain.tld - another instance
- ...
- nameN.jenkins.domain.tld - last instance

One of them works as playground for the main Jenkins - but it's not important.

Is there a way or best practice how to keep and manage many instance of Jenkins? On different host. I don't need share nodes, I know there is gearman tool for this purpose.

At now I'm not 100% sure how it should look. Simple page witch all of instances, to easily switch between them, which run Jenkins web interface in frame. An JS userscript for *.jenkins.domain.tld.

---

I'm back

I'm currently using [Simple Theme Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin) and I've added some JS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
  var switchTool = '<div class="dropdown task" id="switch-jenkins" >'+
    '<a class="task-icon-link" href="#">'+
      '<img class="icon-switch-jenkins icon-md" src="/userContent/image/switch-jenkins.png">'+
    '</a>'+
    '<a class="task-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'+
    'Switch Jenkins to'+
    '</a>'+
    '<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">'+
     '<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="display: none"></a>'+
     '<a class="dropdown-item" href="http://jenkins1.tld'    +  currentUrl  +  '"><img class="icon-switch-jenkins" src="/userContent/image/jenkins1.png">jenkins1</a>'+
     '<a class="dropdown-item" href="http://jenkins2.tld'    +  currentUrl  +  '"><img class="icon-switch-jenkins" src="/userContent/image/jenkins2.png">jenkins2</a>'+
    '</div>'+
  '</div>';
  var switchContainer = $('#side-panel :first').addClass('switch-container');
  switchContainer.prepend(switchTool);
  $('#switch-jenkins').focusout(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("switch-jenkins").style.display="block";},200);
  });
});
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, if you need some kind of a dashboard for  all of those single masters, it is one thing, If you want to access all of those jenkins master in a single browser page, that is another thing.

Comment: No, I don't need access to all of those in a single page.

Comment: Probably I'm looking for some kind of a dashboard as you said.
I've never seen someone who needed several instances of Jenkins, always only one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any established best practices.

I solved this problem by writing a program that generated a HTML page that displayed the all of the jobs across multiple Jenkins masters on a single page. Jobs should have unique names (like "projectA-taskC") so they can be around different masters easily (due to failure, maintenance, load, etc). Whenever things change, just regenerate the HTML page.

CloudBees used to have a product for Jenkins that displayed multiple masters. It sounds like https://www.cloudbees.com/products/continuous-integration sort of does that now, but those focused on administration (vs end-users).